# AVAudioPlayer won't play an mp3 file

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

When I run app, I hear nothing when app plays my MP3 file: "d.mp3".
This file plays okay in iTunes.

I added AVFoundation.framework  to project.
Added file "d.mp3" to project.

Added to view controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Play an MP3 file:
    printf("\n Play an MP3 file");
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"d"
                                         ofType:@"mp3"]];
    printf("\n url = %x", (int)url );
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                                  initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                  error:nil];
    printf("\n audioPlayer = %x", (int)audioPlayer );
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

OUTPUT LOG:

```
Play an MP3 file
url = 3ee78eb0
audioPlayer = 3ee77810
```

Comment: Maybe try passing a non-nil argument to the `error:` argument to see if it's trying to tell you what the problem is?

Comment: I don't believe that AVAudioPlayers retain themselves, which means the player is likely getting deallocated immediately. Can you store it on a strong instance variable and see if that works?

Comment: Don't use `printf` and `%x`. Use `NSLog` and `%@`. This will give you information that is a lot more useful that the pointer address!

Comment: It sounds like a 6-year-old topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-ARC

You have to retain it during playback because it does not retain itself. It will stop playing instantly once it is dealloc-ed.

ARC

You need to hold the AVAudioPlayer instance in the class. And release it after it stops playing. For example,

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface YourController () <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
AVAudioPlayer *_yourPlayer;   // strong reference
}
@end

@implementation YourController

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender
{
  NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"d" withExtension:@"mp3"];
  _yourPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
  _yourPlayer.delegate = self;
  [_yourPlayer play];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (player == _yourPlayer) {
       _yourPlayer = nil;
   }
}

@end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It only works after I move the guts of playAudio into viewDidLoad.